# Detail mod security rules on Cloud Armor WAF

Tags: google-cloud-armor

I've been looking for the detail of every rules at cloud armor WAF. I just found handbook (paid one) and some kind of code regex for every rules. I still didn't find any explainations detail for every rule. Is there any official documentation on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [official documentation on WAF rules for Cloud Armomr here](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rule-tuning) and how to use them in the optimal way.

Additionally you can have a look at the [Cloud Armor documentation](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs) itself - it's a good starting point to get you head around it's concept (configuration, monitoring, troubleshooting and more).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sir. I'm trying to using preconfigured rules on Armor, the description on the table at [this](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rule-tuning) page just an intro and no more details about description every rule. I'm also looking from the CRS documentation at [this](https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset/) page and still didn't find the details.

Comment: WAF rules are written in a specific language that you have to understand a little to be able to utilise the benefits from using it, have you seen the [Google Cloud Armor custom rules language reference](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rules-language-reference) page ? I may not be a book size documentation but it should be a good starter.